Make dryrun available as a tag - possible enhancement
I see the dryrun option from the builder - https://github.com/karatelabs/karate?tab=readme-ov-file#dry-run.
Would it be possible to add this option as a tag so a scenario outline or feature can be evaluated without having to update a runner for the single reference?
This would be beneficial when the business/leadership ask for how a specific change was tested versus what is your entire test suite(s) covering.
